# Can I use "wrapping" as an idiom for "the superficial presentation, rather than the substance"?

Tags: vocabulary, idiomatic-language, idiom-request, idioms-in-context

In my language, one can refer to "the wrapping" as how someone presents an idea when you refer to the form, rather than the idea itself. Is there anything similar in English?

Answer (score 2):

*Packaging* can be used in this sense. (Oxford definition 2 - *the presentation of a person or thing in an advantageous way.*)

Comment: Thanks! If I understand the definitions correctly, it wouldn't be natural to use it to express some philosopher's ideas have "nice packaging but not much substance", right?

Comment: @Probably - nothing wrong with that, in my opinion.